# Is it possible to read from any database file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a database with some tables which were created that are read into my c# application. Is there a way to read the first two columns of any table that is added to the database rather than writing in a query within my code that pulls a specific table? For eg below is my code that reads in the Liguanea_Lane table and populates a autocomplete text field

```
 private void liguaneaRxToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.liguanea_LaneTableAdapter1.Fill(this.pharmaciesDataSet1.Liguanea_Lane);
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            string query = "SELECT Code FROM dbo.Liguanea_Lane";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection mycollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                mycollection.Add(dr.GetString(0));

            }
            textBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = mycollection;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Instead of reading in a specific table and its column, is there a way I could read any table? Meaning let's say I create a table called "Cat_values" How would I read the first or second column of data into my c# code? Rather than having to go into the code each time and execute the query each time a new table is added as demonstrated in the code above

Comment: you could look at the transaction logs.

Comment: I have a lot of questions.  For instance, how do you know *when* a table is added?  How do you know what table it is?  Are you expecting to be able to query "the last table that was created"?  Or some other thing?

Comment: the tables have the same two columns right through. "code" and "description." As for knowing when it is added, it is manually added in the database and the option within my code will be there to select the file to read contents from. the problem is that I don't want to code in each table every time it is added. I would just want to read from that table in which the database it is added to

Comment: The biggest issue here is there is not enough information provided for us to be able to help you. In short, what you need before you can get an answer, is a question. As posted this is not a complete question so any answer is going to be either a partial answer or a guess.

Comment: Okay let me ask the question with more clarity. I have a C# UI which I want to read any file from a sql database. To expand further is that if I should add a table with data to sql, I would want my UI to read the first two columns of that table without having to create code within my application for that specific table. So like you would have  a query that says "SELECT code FROM table," instead of writing a query each time to pull form that respective table you would instead have a query that pulls from a specific column within a table no matter what table is added to the database.

Comment: So my final question is, if it is possible to have a query to pull data from a column from any table that is added within a database rather than having to code a query that has the exact name  of the table and also its column name

Comment: So I would want something like this:

I click on a button which ends up pulling up all the tables that have been added. When I select one it automatically pulls the column for it based on the code/query created within the C# code

Comment: If the columns are always the same it shouldn't be that hard. Do you know the tables name? Are they following any scheme like table_1, table_2 etc.? Else every Database has the possibility to access the table list. I think you just need one select and replace the from clause each time.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that but the end users might just add any table name. So am wondering if it is better to instruct them on the naming each file should have

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the table names within your database by executing the following query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM YOURDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

In order to manage which tables are added since your last check, you might create a table which holds all existing table names like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DatabaseTables](
    [TableName] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [DateAdded] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
)
```

Each time you inspect the added tables, execute the statement below to update the table containing the database tables:

```
INSERT INTO DatabaseTables(TableName)
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM YOURDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT TableName FROM DatabaseTables)
```